What pear-shaped vegetable is growing in my soil?
In Vancouver (Canada) after a fairly cool summer 2024, I was surprised to find a vegetable growing in my garden soil. What is it?

they were around 8 inches (20 cm) below ground
they have a diameter of around 1.5 inch (3.75 cm)
many of them were growing close together
it is possible that they have been growing there for years without being noticed




closeup
surrounding area










Vegetable? They look like bulbs to me... Such as Hyacinth maybe...

Pick few of them.. plant them in a pot..take care..you will get the results.. come back with them, if you still don't recognise.

Note: also some wild plants/weeds may have bulbs.
